# Build zeutro/openabe on vs2019

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2019

I am dev a project. I have found a library that implements my idea. This is https://github.com/zeutro/openabe. In this library, they have some tutorial to build in linux and windows. But I am developing my project in VS2019. I am trying build it in linux and find some solution for convert .a library to .lib. But I found the answer that it is not possible.

So, how can I build openabe for using in vs2019. I'm really in a hurry with my thesis.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if openabe isn't cross platform you'll need to find another library

Comment: So is it possible when i want to use .a library on visual studio. If possible, just help me.